# Game of Life - Algorithmic Issue C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

Alright, so I am coding the game of life, I am almost done, but I am having troubles with the algorithm used to make cells alive and dead, it can be found in the function calculate.

Here is the input I am getting: http://ideone.com/ywEtC

And here is a screenie (found in comments) from a site with the same pattern I used, and it shows the intended output.

I have tried making it so that it doesn't count newly created cells as neighbors, but that turned out even worse. The source for that for reference can be found here: https://github.com/Legitimate/Conway-s-Game-of-Life/blob/master/gameoflife4.cpp

Comment: Here is the intended output: http://i.minus.com/iIPLE7LoZSU7t.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You problem is that you need to double buffer, because after you changed a value, other values won't know its original value.
e.g.

```
---
+++
---
```

(0, 1): it has 1 neighbor and must die:

```
---
-++
---
```

(1, 1): it has 1 neighbor and must die:

```
---
--+
---
```

(2, 1): it has 0 neighbors and must die:

```
---
---
---
```

while the excpected output will be:

```
-+-
-+-
-+-
```

Also, the use of char array is highly inefficient, you need to warp `bit_vector` to make it two dimensional, it will also make double buffering easier.

Comment: This is the best thing I have ever heard on the internet. Now I get why people have 2 2D Arrays in their sources. Thanks dude!